# ArangoDB create collections and graph from one document

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I have one collection with documents. In the documents there are buyer, seller and contract name plus many more attributes.
I well now create a graph for this.
So I take out the attributes for buyer, seller and contract and place them in there one documents collections.
Then I make one edge collection “contract_of” where I link them together.

When I change NEW._to to NEW._id I get the graph, but it only shows ID’s so I change the nodes label to D_CONTRACT_AWARD_BAYER and the name of the buyers show, but I cant add D_CONTRACT_AWARD_BAYER, D_CONTRACT_AWARD_SELLAR_OFFICIALNAME

This is the code that I try to run.

```
FOR v IN FORM_3_V2_TEST
  LET a = v.D_CONTRACT_AWARD_BAYER
  LET s = v.D_CONTRACT_AWARD_SELLAR_OFFICIALNAME
  LET t = v.D_CONTRACT_AWARD_TITLE_CONTRACT
  FILTER a
  FILTER s
  FILTER t
  LET fid = (INSERT {D_CONTRACT_AWARD_BAYER: a} INTO bayer RETURN NEW._from)[0]
  LET sid = (INSERT {D_CONTRACT_AWARD_SELLAR_OFFICIALNAME: s} INTO sellar RETURN NEW._to)[0]
  LET tid = (INSERT {D_CONTRACT_AWARD_TITLE_CONTRACT: t} INTO contract RETURN NEW.D_CONTRACT_AWARD_TITLE_CONTRACT)[0]
  INSERT {_from: fid, _to: sid, contract: tid } INTO contract_of
  RETURN [fid, sid, tid]
```

I well have label to seller name and buyer name and the contract title one the edges label.

Comment: What do you mean by "it only shows ID’s". Your solution is wrong because `_from` in `bayer` collection and `_to` in `sellar` colecttion are `null` values. The provided code must fail with `edge attribute missing or invalid` error. Use `_id` and please explain the problem you are having more.